# Web browsers fetching css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I think this is a straightforward question, but I'm having a hard time finding specifics. In a simplified world, let's suppose we have one html file that has references to .js and .css files. The browser sends the HTTP request and receives the .html, and then sees that there are dependencies and sends corresponding HTTP requests for the .css and .js files. Is there something special about these secondary HTTP requests? I ask because I have set up a simple HTTP server, and when it receives a request for '/' it returns index.html, but somehow the browser also has the proper styling and scripts, although I haven't configured anything in the server to handle requests for these files. What's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. There are other StackExchange sites more suitable for your question.

Comment: No, they're plain simple GET requests. The browser is the one responsible for rendering HTML, parsing and executing JS and parsing and applying CSS rules.

Comment: In the case that this is implementation specific, I'm using express.js inside node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the subsequent paths are probably url's pointing to a specific location on your server, while your '/' url is not pointing to anything specific. Your server will:

1. Recieve this request and recognize it as the default route
2. Try to resolve it (index.html is in a list of files that he will use to resolve this route).

The url's for your js files on the other hand, are probably:

```
http://www.example.com/js/yourJsFileName.js
```

When the server retrieves this request, it will look in the file system for wwwroot\js\yourJsFileName.js. I hope this answers your question, and I understood it correctly... Also, this explanation was too long for a comment ;)

Comment: gotchya, so it's resolving based on the root location. thank you!